# Upload multiple images with description?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is it possible to upload multiple images with its description in php?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $gn_id=$_POST['gn_id'];
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT INTO `add_gallery` (`id`, `gn_id`, `photo`, `desc`, `date`) VALUES ('', '$gn_id', '$file_name', '$desc', '$date')";

        $desired_dir="gallery";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("../$desired_dir", 0700);     // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("../$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="../$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         $qu=mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you kindly add your html for better understanding.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson : How? Help me ! Any Example Links

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya If you look at the question, multiple upload isn't the OP's issue. It's adding descriptions to the files (which Mr Developer have answered below).

Comment: use `<input name="description[]" value="first image Desc"/>` and so on as per your requirement. then access them as `$_POST['description'][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this task by post description values as array.

```
<input name="description[]" value="First Image" />
<input name="description[]" value="Second Image"  />
<input name="description[]" value="Third Image" />
<input name="description[]" value="Fourth Image" />
<input name="description[]" value="Fifth Image" />
```

Then

```
$_POST['description'][0] == 'First Image'
$_POST['description'][3] == 'Fourth Image'
```

Once you post the values then you can get in your foreach loop. In the loop you can get current image description by using current index description array

```
// Getting description values as arrays
$Description_Values = $_POST['description'];
// Below iteration counter
$Counter = 0;
// This is your foreach loop which you are using for images
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
// Getting Current Image Description
$current_image_description = $Description_Values[$Counter];
$Counter++;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$Description_Values[$Counter];`, why not use `$Description_Values[$key];`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes we can use. Thanks for sharing this +1

Comment: Thanks Mr. Developer. It works perfectly.  And Thanks  
@MagnusEriksson